# Gmail send message to self and see it in inbox

Tags: gmail

I have a contact form on a website that uses gmail to send the message. That gmail account sends the message to itself.

This means the message does not appear in the inbox. Any ideas how I can get it to appear in the inbox?

I'm using Alias'

I've tested and if I send a message from myID@mydomain.com to myID@mydomain.com it appears in the inbox fine. However when I send a message from myalias@myotherdomain.com to myalias@myotherdomain.com then it does not appear in the inbox

Ideas I've looked at:

With filters I can apply any label apart from inbox, and I can skip in inbox, but there's no "put it in the inbox" options.

I do not want to send from the main ID address (as the client's are cc'd into the message and the alias is more appropriate)

Any ideas please? I feel this should be easy but after a lot of googling I cannot find anything.

Comment: You should definitely see the mail in the inbox. Please check if you receive the mail when sending it to different receiver. I think it is very likely that the message does not even get sent, because as per default the message will appear in the inbox. How do you send the message? Gmail has very strong restrictions towards 3rd party clients or sending not through the official app/website.

Comment: I've tested and the message does sent fine. 

in my test  the website contact form sends from me@mydomain.com to me@mydomain.com, and cc's the client in on client@gmail.com. The client is receiving their copy fine, and for me@mydomain.com it's just in the all mail bit

Comment: Correction: I'm using alias. It's sending both from and to an alias, and that has the issue. I've done a test just in gmail and sending from myID@mydomain.com to myID@mydomain.com works fine - it appears in the inbox. 

However when I send from myAlias@mydomain.com to myAlias@mydomain.com it does not appear in the inbox

I've corrected above. Thanks

Comment: If youI want to send from myAlias@mydomain.com to myAlias@mydomain.com and receive the message in myID@mydomain.com Gmail inbox, check the Treat as an alias box: https://support.google.com/a/answer/1710338

Answer (score 5):

From Google:

*To prevent clutter, Gmail doesn't route messages that you send to your own alias (or to a group you belong to) to your inbox. You can find the message in Sent Mail or All Mail.*

https://support.google.com/a/answer/1703601?hl=en

**Solution**

Make it To the alias address (so clients see the correct email address) but also bcc the message to the google id, then the email appears in the inbox.

Answer (score 1):

In the Google contacts for the account in question, remove itself as a contact.
Then try to send a message from the account to itself and see if it shows up.
If autocomplete is important, try re-adding the account to contacts manually and disabling the feature in Gmail that automatically creates new contacts.

https://contacts.google.com/u/1/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this same issue because I had a filter set up. I deleted the filter and now its working as I would like.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop the message from Sent folder to Inbox folder.  (I did it in Claws Mail but it should work with any IMAP client.)

Answer (score -1):

Switching off `Treat as an Alias` in google's settings for the e-mail fixed it for me.

Comment: User is still able to send by default from non g-mail account, I couldn't see any downside as of yet, I wasn't really sure what the option did anyway so I'll likely leave it ticked in the future.